# How to keep track of database updates associated with Jira issues?

Tags: mysql, database, version-control, deployment, jira

We are using Jira as our issue-tracker, and our team works with mercurial repositories. When a developer makes a database change that is associated with a jira issue, he adds the sql as a comment on the issue. The problem with this is - when it comes time to push these issues to our production site, I need to browse through each issue going live to see which ones have db updates in their comments. There has to be a better way!!

Our production mysql db is on a shared host that does not allow us direct access. Any sql updates I want to go live need to be emailed in a sql file to be imported.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe is a common problem when developing against a database. The usual solution is "database versioning".

The basic idea is that different states of your schema (i.e. your tables, columns, stored procedures etc.) get different version numbers. Then scripts for migrating between schema versions are created and stored.

Be warned that you'll likely need to fundamentally change your workflow. I don't think having the SQL code for migration in JIRA is a sustainable strategy. SQL is code, and belongs into the code repository.

See e.g. this question for details and techniques: [Database Schema Versioning Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950344/database-schema-versioning-strategies)

Comment: thanks, this is a different way of looking at things that makes much more sense. i will check out the info in the link. we're still a pretty small dev team, so changing our workflow is not a big deal now.